# jQuery getJSON not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I am trying to get some data back from a server using jQuery `$.getJSON`, and the code seems to work fine, until it gets to `$.getJSON`, it doesn't seem to be triggering that at all, there are no console logs when I press the button, here is the code below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var funk;
    $('#button').live('click', function(){
        var funk = "";
        var query = "";
        $('#wrapper > [data-custom="field"]').each(function(i, data){

            if(i == 0){
                funk = query + $(this).attr('id')+" = '"+$(this).val()+"'";
            }else{
                funk = funk + " AND " + $(this).attr('id')+" = '"+$(this).val()+"'";
            };

        }); 

        $.getJSON('test.php', {query: funk}, function(json){
            console.log(json)
        });

    });
});
```

the PHP file test.php in the same folder,

```
$weo = $_GET['query'];

echo $weo;
```

Any ideas on what could be causing the problem?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the call is getting to the server? I would start by stripping the code down and pass a hard-coded "funk" value to track down the problem. Also if the server is throwing an error (e.g. HTTP status 400) then the success function wouldn't be called and you wouldn't your log see on the console (although you would probably see an error being logged?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are debugging using:

-> Firefox: open Firebug and look at the Net tab to make sure the request is firing, and to see what the response from the server is.

-> IE: Fire up Fiddler2 to see the request/response.

-> Chrome: use the Resources tab.

Once you see what the server is returning (if anything), you can figure out how to proceed.

Comment: I was using firebug, nothing was firing, after a restart it just worked, once again windows fails, but thanx for all of the help! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I expect that getJSON is falling over because the server is not returning nice JSON syntax.

Try doing

```
echo json_encode($weo);
```

in your PHP file.  If you don't ultimately want to use JSON, but plain text instead, use `$.get`:

```
$.get('test.php', {query: funk}, function(data){
    console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: Still nothing, I am not getting any error message either, this is really bizarre!

Answer (score 0):

For sure your Test.php is not working as expected. To debug what is being returned back from the server try this code

```
function AjaxDebug() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.php",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: ({query: funk}),
    success: function(results) {
        alert("Success!");
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
    }
}); }
```

Then try having the break point in error and examine the XMLHttpRequest.getresponseText, getresponseXML etc to have a better understanding of what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with getJSON not working. I noticed that data gets loaded but is not available to use.

The solution is to use JSONP and in the url querystring add a callback function variable.

```
 $.getJSON("http://www.example.com/test.php?callback=?",function(json){
        console.log(json);
    });
```

Note that we put a ? as the callback function name instead of a real function name. This is because jQuery replaces the ? with a generated function name (like jsonp1232617941775) that calls the inline function.

In your PHP you will need to output with the callback function.

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $jsonData . ');';
// prints: jsonp1232617941775({"name" : "Gaurav", "age" : "91"});
```

This will output valid JSONP object and you will be able to load and use in your jQuery code.